# show/hide content when hovering menu dont work

Tags: html, css, hover

Cant manage to work this. I want to hover menu  element, and when i hover it shows gallery class.

I did put .gallery class display: none;
and 
.main_menu ul li a:hover + .gallery

should change gallery display to block, but it just doesnt shows up ;)

HTML for the menu and gallery

```
<div class="main_menu">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="shop">shop</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">collections </a></li>
   <li><a href="#">gifts</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">moodboard</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
</ul><br />
</div>

<!--gallery hover-->
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="item1">
    <img src="images/item_1.png" width="166" height="129" class="item_1" alt="*" />
    <div class="description">
    <span>Artwork</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
   <img src="images/item_2.png" width="166" height="129" class="item_1" alt="*" />
<div class="description">
    <span>Bedding</span>
</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery{
    position:absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    width: 980px;
    min-height: 300px;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    display: none;
}

.main_menu ul li a:hover + .gallery {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: where is gallery html?

Comment: Where is the `.gallery`?

Comment: None of your elements have the class you're describing?

Comment: is there a reason for the `<br />` in the HTML?

Comment: From the css I assume, gallery is sibling of <a/> in <li> e.g. <li><a href="#" class="shop">shop</a>
            <div class="gallery">something</div>
        </li>... and this works fine.

Comment: updated gallery class

Comment: It looks like you want `.gallery` to be displayed whenever any of the links are moused over.  Is this right?

Comment: yes that right, just want to make it work and then think about only showing it when hovering shop link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+ .gallery` is a sibling selector, so the `.gallery` element will need to be a sibling of the element with the `:hover` selector.

You will either need to change the location of .gallery or change which element will trigger the :hover.

Linked is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/Xe9Ew/) that shows a couple of options.

In the first, `<div class="gallery">` has been moved to be a sibling of the first anchor tag with class `.shop`.

In the second example, the selector has been changed to: `.main_menu2:hover + .gallery2` so that any hover over the entire menu will trigger the display of `.gallery2`.

Hopefully this will give you a better idea of how the sibling selector works with `:hover` and you can adjust it to something that works for your needs.

Comment: You can make the hover active on `li` and change the positioning of `.gallery` a bit to get the effect you want.  Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/Xe9Ew/1/)

Comment: tnx, work perfect. I want to add a little thing. could u help me out. I have on shop link,  a css style `.main_menu ul li a:hover{bg image...}` and i added `.gallery:hover{display:block;}` so when i hover shop, i can hover .gallery class and it will be visable, but then shops background disapears becouse i hovered .gallery class, how can i make so .gallery and background of shop link both are visable ?

Answer (score 0):

For a `hover` pseudo-class you use `>` as such.

```
.main_menu ui li a:hover > .gallery
```

Answer (score 0):

a:hover + .gallery means .gallery has to be sibling of  which is not the case in your html.

rather use jquery to handle mouseenter and mouseleave events to show/hide .gallery

```
$(function(){
    $(".main_menu ul li > a")
    .on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(".gallery").show();
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(".gallery").hide();
    });
});
```

This is a sample code for handling hover behavior. modify it to show whatever element you want based on the hovered menu item.

Comment: is there a solution how can i select that gallery class when hoverking ?

Comment: you have one gallery. on hover of a menu item what do you want to show? not the same gallery I suppose. can you elaborate?